# Insufficent network fees

Tags: fees, coinbase

I get the message, "The ETH balance in your parent account is insufficient for network fees" when I try to send my ECR20 Matic tokens from my Leger to my coinbase account. Instead of sending the full amount I tried sending less so the fees could be covered but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For all transaction in Ethereum,gas fees are paid in its native currency, ether (ETH).So,you need to sufficient eth for transferring erc20 tokens too.